# what does this formula stand for?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$|x|+|y|=1$ seems to be some shape in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but I have no way of discovering which shape this might be...

Comment: Have you tried to plot some graph yourself? That may help.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest first drawing it in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ using the variables $(x,y)$. Since there is no constraint on a third variable z, you essentially extend the entire shape into the third dimension.

For example, the equation $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ defines a circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and extends to an infinite cylinder in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: What makes you think there is a third variable?

Comment: Asker mentioned that it represents a shape in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Wolfram Alpha or other graphing technology to plot it for a clue.

Because $|x|= \pm x$ and likewise for $y$, this is a combination of four equations. Try splitting it into four possibilities. All four equations are line segments, so the graph of this is going to be $4$ line segments, one for each quadrant. I wouldn't assume it's a $3d$ shape because there is no $z$, unless context suggests otherwise.

Can you finish?